# Query regarding DefaultSelenium class argument constructor's arguments?

Tags: selenium-rc

I am writing my first automation program with Selenium RC & i have a couple of queries. Please have a look at the sample code:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class TestGoogle
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://google.com");

        selenium.start();
        selenium.open("/");
        selenium.windowMaximize();
        selenium.windowFocus();
    }
}
```

Query 1: In the first argument, i have passed "localhost" because the RC server is running locally on my machine. In case the rc serer is running on a remote machine, how would i pass it. What is the syntax?

Query 2: In the third argument, i have passed "*firefox". I do not understand why is * used when the program runs fine without using it? Also is it also possible to give the absolute path. I have tried it but it is not working?

Kindly suggest,
Regards.

Comment: Waiting for comments.

Comment: 5 hours isn't very long to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Replace "localhost" with the IP address or DNS hostname of the machine where the Selenium RC server is running.
2. The `*firefox` browser-spec specifies Firefox from one of several default locations.  If you want a specific location, use the `*custom` browser-spec.

Selenium RC documentation is at http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html.

Comment: Thanks Ross for your reply.